# GLCanvas serializing

Tags: java, opengl, serialization, jogl, glcanvas

In my app I use JOGL lib to work with OpenGL.

I need to serialize my implementation of javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas.

```
import javax.media.opengl.*;
import javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas;
import javax.media.opengl.glu.GLU;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Canvas extends GLCanvas implements GLEventListener, Serializable {
private GLU glu;

private static final int FPS = 60;
private FPSAnimator animator;

public Canvas() {
    addGLEventListener(this);
}

@Override
public void init(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
    drawable.setGL(new DebugGL2(drawable.getGL().getGL2()));

    glu = new GLU();

    animator = new FPSAnimator(this, FPS);
    animator.start();
}

@Override
public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
    if (!animator.isAnimating()) return;
    final GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();

    gl.glClear(GL2.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL2.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    setCamera(gl, glu, camera.getHeight(), camera.getOrigin());
}

@Override
public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable drawable, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
    final GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
    gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}

@Override
public void dispose(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {

}

private void setCamera(GL2 gl, GLU glu, float distance, Float origin) {
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_PROJECTION);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();

    float widthHeightRatio = (float) getWidth() / (float) getHeight();
    glu.gluPerspective(45, widthHeightRatio, 1, 1000);
    glu.gluLookAt(origin.x, origin.y, distance, origin.x, origin.y, 0, 0, 1, 0);

    gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
}
}
```

I try write to object my Canvas

```
   fout = new FileOutputStream("F:\\canvas.ser");
   oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);
   oos.writeObject(mCanvas);
```

But I have error:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: com.jogamp.nativewindow.awt.AWTGraphicsConfiguration
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
at com.pms.efficiency.VideoEffectiveApplication.saveFileAs(VideoEffectiveApplication.java:328)
at com.pms.efficiency.VideoEffectiveApplication.lambda$initMenu$1(VideoEffectiveApplication.java:215)
at java.awt.MenuItem.processActionEvent(MenuItem.java:669)
at java.awt.MenuItem.processEvent(MenuItem.java:628)
at java.awt.MenuComponent.dispatchEventImpl(MenuComponent.java:351)
at java.awt.MenuComponent.dispatchEvent(MenuComponent.java:339)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:761)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

So, fields in GLCanvas are not serializeble. What can I do?

Comment: Not sure if this may solve your problem, but `javax.media.opengl` suggests you are using an outdated jogl version

Comment: You can use the Reflection API to set the unserializable fields to null during the serialization or wrap the GLCanvas into a custom class implementing Externalizable and completely override the default serialization but it's very difficult :s